# What are the books about creating own *nix OS?

Tags: architecture

I want to create my own Unix OS. Is there any book that I can learn from, from start?

Comment: Define "want to create my own Unix OS". Do you mean developing an operating system from scratch, or just building your own distribution?

Comment: i want to create my operating system, just that. standing hardware on feet and calling my scripts. and i use unix based operating systems so i want my operating system unix based. starting from the most beginning.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you will get any printed book on this topic. The best resource you should consider is [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)(Linux from Scratch).

It is a type of Linux distribution and book which teaches you how to build your own Linux distribution from source.

Answer (score 6):

In case you meant "create my own UNIX OS" literally, maybe you're interested in the resources surrounding [xv6 ("a simple Unix-like teaching operating system")](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/xv6.html), or ["The Design and Implementation of the 4.4BSD Operating System"](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/design-44bsd/book.html).

**Edit** Just stumbled upon this, ["McIlroy's annotated guide to research Unix"](http://pic.plover.com/UnixReader/), which probably also is related.  (And please read @nimrodm's Plan 9 hint closely `:)`)

Answer (score 4):

While I understand that you want a UNIX system, I think it is worthwhile to take a look at a few more modern operating systems.

[Plan9](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/) from Bell Labs is from the same people who created UNIX and takes the same philosophy to the extreme (everything is a file, simplicity, composing small tools). Plan9 is a monolithic (but small) traditional kernel.

[QNX](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~voelker/cse221/papers/qnx-paper92.pdf) is a commercial microkernel (see also openqnx) that shares some resemblance (at least superficially) to UNIX but is a more radical design.

Finally, [MINIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINIX_3) is another example of a UNIX inspired microkernel and is accompanied by a good book describing its design and internals.

I highly recommend reading about the above systems before embarking on your own project.

Comment: I wouldn't call Plan9's kernel "traditional" and "monolithic". Its distributed design (9P as the central protocol) makes it non-traditional, and the client/server architecture (file server, CPU server, authentication server, etc.) makes it non-monolithic.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to develop your own UNIX-like OS, on top of @sr_ answer I would suggest [Lions' Commentary on Unix](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1573980137), [The Design of the UNIX Operating System](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132017997), and perhaps [Operating Systems Design and Implementation](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/academic/product/0,,0131429388,00+en-USS_01DBC.html) to see how a microkernel based UNIX-like OS can be implemented.